# System.err.println and System.out.println not getting in log file

Tags: java, spring, error-logging, system.out, system.err

I have developed new Spring webservice and had few System.out.println and System.err.println debug line in my code. This webservice ear is deployed to IBM WAS server. But i am not seeing those debug statement in SystemOut.log and SystemErr.log files. But other ear's debug statement in same WAS server is getting printed in those log file.

Can some one help me why my new ear debug statement alone not getting into log files?

Comment: Why are you using the `System` streams instead of a proper logger?

Comment: Yes i know. But for short term due to continuous integration, we need to take logging implementation in our next release.

Comment: Adding proper logging is very quick. Just add slf4j and logback and replace your System streams with a logger object.